# on Focus not working when textbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, onfocus

I have a form here which id like the users to be able to select the radio button to choose a pre-defined amount option, or press the textbox (focus) to select the custom amount. The purpose of the javascript below is to clear the textbox when a predefined amount has been selected. It also allows users to CLICK the textbox (onfocus) to enter a custom amount in the CP_otheramount field (also use the radio button as a fallback).

It all seems to be working except for the onfocus. It works perfectly on load...but try this scenario:

Load the page, click inside the textbox but then decide to change your mind by selecting the value 3 radio button (64)...and then decide to press inside the onfocus textbox amount again... it become disabled and stops you from clicking inside or writing a number in!

Can anyone see the problem here at all? Its strange because it works on Stackoverflow just not on the live site. ANy help would be really appreciated.

Here is what has been created so far:

```js
function activate() {
  $('#other').prop('checked', true);
  $('#other').trigger('click');
  $('#theamount').focus();
}
$('input[name="am_payment"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val('');
    $('#theamount').removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $('#theamount').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked="checked"> <strong>64</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11" checked="checked"> <strong>100</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32" checked="checked"> <strong>250</strong>

<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment" id="other">
<label>Other</label>

<span onclick="activate();"><input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled"/></span>
```

Comment: cannot click textbox on page load since you have added an attribute disabled, So unless clicking on other radio button it is not getting enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing a textbox field when a radio button is selected in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916173/clearing-a-textbox-field-when-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript) and [clearing-a-textbox-when-any-other-radio-buttons-are-selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938031/clearing-a-textbox-when-any-other-radio-buttons-are-selected)

Comment: If the textbox is disabled it can't get focus.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are checking every radio button without un-checking them.

```
function activate() {
  // $('#other').prop('checked', true); Remove this line;
  $('#other').trigger('click');
  $('#theamount').focus();
}
$('input[name="am_payment"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val('');
    $('#theamount').removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $('#theamount').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val('');
  }
});
```

And also

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Only check one, or none by Default -->
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked = "checked"> <strong>64</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11"> <strong>100</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32"> <strong>250</strong>

<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment" id="other">
<label>Other</label>

<span onclick="activate();"><input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled"/></span>
```

**UPDATE:**

It was working for me but I don't know why it's not working for you, so I rewrote the functions..See if this works for you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked = "checked"> <strong>64</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11"> <strong>100</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32"> <strong>250</strong>

<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment" id="other">
<label>Other</label>

<span id="toggle"><input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled"/></span>

<script>
    function activate(){
        $('#theamount').attr('disabled',false);
        $('#theamount').focus();
        $('#other').click();
    }

    function deactivate(){
        $('#theamount').val('');
        $('#theamount').attr('disabled',true);
    }

    $('#toggle').click(function(){
        activate();
    });
    $('input[name="am_payment"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ""){
            deactivate();
        }else{
            activate();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have done the above, but the textbox still does not let you click inside it if you first select a radio button for values 100 (or 64 or 250) and then go other BY clicking or pressing inside the textbox.